# Hosting a database?

Tags: database

I was kinda puzzled by seeing that most hosting plans do offer, say, 12.000 MB disk space and 60 MB Database space... what is the difference between this two and what do I do if I need like a few gigs for a database and only some tens of MB for the rest of the site?

Comment: aha... found a hosting company called ipage.com , they seem to offer MySQL Databases - Unlimited. Anybody heard of them? is that true?

Comment: wtf with your previous question?

Comment: what a stupid habit of deleting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the disk space and database space are on two different servers (Disk Space is on the Web Server, Database space is on the Database Server...hence the different numbers).

If you need specialized amounts of disk space on either server, you should look in to a more specialized hosting plan. Otherwise you're going to pay for the bundle and then under-utilize your resources.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to use web space for data storage is to use an in Memory database like SQLite.

http://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of files and database you will be hosting but the "standard" setup uses a lot more disk space than database space and this is why the standard offer is presented this way. If you are hosting files, you will typically host the files on the file server and save links to them in the database. In this scenario the database will not get very big.

If you really need a database with several gigabytes of data for hosting huge amounts of text you will need to contact the hosting company for a more specialized offer, or host it yourself.

Comment: I would be hosting lost of text data, about 5 mb / month per user.
Therefor if I would have at least 100 users, in two month it would already be a gig.

Answer (score 0):

if website/web application you want to do , google app engine is a good option, both for webspace and database. free goodies of 1GB space is irresistible.